# Linq group by multiple fields across different tables

Tags: c#, linq

In an attempt to convert this SQL query to LINQ I have hit a problem with group by. 
How can I group by multiple columns that originate from multiple tables?
The linq query below simply won't compile so I'm in need of the correct syntax

#### Original SQL Query

```
select LTRIM(RTRIM(e.Shortname)) 
Name, LTRIM(RTRIM(j.JobName)) 
JobName, j.JobCode, 
SUM(Hours) Hours, 
MAX(ce.LatestTimesheetEntry) LastTimeSubmitted 
from TWCTL.TW.Postings p
join TWCTL.TW.Employees e on e.EmployeeId = p.EmployeeId
join TWCTL.TW.Jobs j on j.JobCode = p.JobCode
join CentralTimeEmployees.dbo.Employees ce on ce.CtEmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
where (e.CostCentreId = 1 or e.CostCentreId = 3) 
and (p.TransactionDate >= '2012-01-01' and p.TransactionDate <= '2012-07-01') 
and j.JobCode <> 'CTCIT00001' 
and ce.DatabaseCode = 'CTL' 
and (ce.CostCentreId = 1 or ce.CostCentreId = 3)
group by j.JobName, j.JobCode, Shortname
order by e.Shortname, j.JobName
```

#### Linq Query attempt (not working)

```
var model = 
        from p in context.Postings
        join e in context.Employees on p.EmployeeId equals e.EmployeeId
        join j in context.Jobs on p.JobCode equals j.JobCode
        join ce in context.CentralTimeEmployees on e.EmployeeId equals ce.CtEmployeeId
        where (e.CostCentreId == 5 || e.CostCentreId == 3)
                && (p.TransactionDate >= fromDate
                    && p.TransactionDate <= toDate)
                && j.JobCode != "CTCIT00001"
                && ce.DatabaseCode == "CTL"
                && (ce.CostCentreId == 1 || ce.CostCentreId == 3)
        group j by new {j.JobName, j.JobCode} into g1
        group e by e.Shortname into g2    <- doesnt work??        
        select
            new ProjectHoursViewModel
                {Posting = p, Job = g1.Key.JobName, Employee = e, CentralTimeEmployee = ce};
```

Comment: And it's not working because there's an error...? Got the wrong results...? What?

Comment: @JeffMercado I've updated the post, basically the syntax is incorrect and won't compile, I need some assistance in the group by area. Ta

Comment: @PaulStoker: does the compiler give you a reason it is refusing to compile it? I would think though its something to do with the multiple group bys but I only ever use method syntax for linq so I am not sure exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For starters, your query is not equivalent. Minor things really like different values being checked but a major one is that you don't group by the same keys.  The SQL grouped by JobCode which you left out in your query.  And you attempted to group too much instead of ordering it.  The values you are aggregating should be what you are grouping.

As for why you're getting the syntax error, after you do a continuation (using `into` in a `group by` or `select` clause), all the variables in the previous scope are lost and only the continuation variable remains (`g1` in your case).  You tried to reference `e` which is now out of scope giving you the problem.

The query should be  more like this I think:

```
var fromDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
var toDate = new DateTime(2012, 7, 1);
var query = 
    from p in dc.Postings
    join e in dc.Employees on p.EmployeeId equals e.EmployeeId
    join j in dc.Jobs on p.JobCode equals j.JobCode
    join ce in dc.CentralTimeEmployees on e.EmployeeId equals ce.CtEmployeeId
    where (e.CostCentreId == 1 || e.CostCentreId == 3) // the SQL tested 1 or 3
       && (p.TransactionDate >= fromDate && p.TransactionDate <= toDate)
       && j.JobCode != "CTCIT00001"
       && ce.DatabaseCode == "CTL"
       && (ce.CostCentreId == 1 || ce.CostCentreId == 3)
    group new { ce.Hours, ce.LatestTimesheetEntry }
       by new { j.JobName, j.JobCode, e.ShortName } into g
    orderby g.Key.ShortName, g.Key.JobName
    select new
    {
        Name = g.Key.ShortName.Trim(),
        JobName = g.Key.JobName.Trim(),
        JobCode = g.Key.JobCode,
        Hours = g.Sum(x => x.Hours),
        LastTimeSubmitted = g.Max(x => x.LatestTimesheetEntry),
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, that pretty much did the trick, I nearly had it in two separate queries but I didnt really want to do that ;-)

Comment: In above query, how can we use count() function. I tried `g.Count(x => x.JobCode)` but it's throwing an error - `Cannot implicitly convert type ******** to bool`. Is there any other of doing count operation?

Comment: @RohitSawai: By passing a lambda to the `Count()` function, it's a predicate to select items you want to count. It should return a boolean value, much like the `Where()`, `First()`, or `Single()` functions among others.

Comment: @JeffMercado Thank you for that explaination which made think and got solution to my problem. I was blindly mirroring above code for making count() function work. Your explanation guided me, how to implement what I wanted.