# How to design nested query for fetching data from tables of MS SQL using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I have three tables which you can see in following diagram:

[image]

My problem is, I want to return all problems, its responses and the count of of seen status i.e. those responses which has not seen yet. I'm using Entity framework. I have used following query:

```
querySelection = (from problems in db.Problems
              join response in db.Response on problems.Id equals response.QueryId
              join order in db.Msg_Orders on response.Id equals order.Response_Id
              join seen_status in db.Seen_Status on order.Order_Id equals seen_status.OrderId
              select new QuerySelect{
                Problem_State = problems.Problem_State,
                Response = response.Response,
                ResponseCount = /*What code should I write here*/
              }).ToList();
```

I have 2 problems with my above query:

1. **Expectation**: It should return only unique problems and unseen response count

   **What result getting**: As Msg_Orders have multiple problem Ids and above query returning same result multiple times
2. Not understanding how to add count of unseen status inside above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Jeff Mercado's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11524543/9282474) and its comment for figuring out what exact I can do and how can I modify query in the form of Entity Framework syntax. For achieving my goal, I needed to use `GROUP BY` clause with `INNER JOIN` in the Entity Framework syntax.

I have written following solution which solved above problem:

```
querySelection = (from problems in db.Problems
              join response in db.Response on problems.id equals response.Query_Id
              join order in db.Msg_Orders on query.id equals order.query_id
              join seen_status in db.Seen_Status on order.Order_id equals seen_status.Order_id
              group new { problems, response, order ,seen_status }
                by new
                {
                    problems.Id,
                    problems.Problem_State,
                    problems.Created_Date,
                    response.Response,
                    seen_status.User_Seen_Status
                } into grp
              orderby grp.Key.Id descending
              select new QuerySelection
              {
                  Id = grp.Key.Id,
                  Problem_State = grp.Key.Problem_State,
                  Created_Date = grp.Key.Created_Date,
                  Response = grp.Key.Response,
                  TotalResp = grp.Count(x => x.seen_status.user_seen == 0) // Counting total number of responses
              }
              ).ToList();
```